# How to protect IP-sensitive data in files generated by- and used by- users

Tags: security, encoding, decoding

I'm working on an offline windows application that generates and loads key results as files. However, these files provide key insights into how our product works internally. To make matters worse my users will for sure be tech savvy. So if I do not encode it, we give away our magic. So given this problem, I have some questions:

- Is there an encryption method commonly used to make files unreadable (or at least hard to read) except for (multiple instances of) a certain application?
- How hard is it to read what assets (like private keys) are baked into a .dll file?

Comment: Probably your question fit better in security sister site (look at the top right icon). OTOH it seems you know very little about security, so your battle to some tech-savvy people is already lost. My tip: depend less on the "magic". Good interface, many improvements, new versions, good marketing makes cloning less interesting. [Look popular programs: their are hacked, and they have a lot of resources. OS may have some API, but then you should apply to their security programs]

Comment: Sure, I will post it in the security stack. And yes I'm well aware I'm new to encryption and that this problem cannot never be 100% solved, hence the annotation "or at least hard to read". The answers to my questions in the post will indeed influence overall design and strategy. Since you seem to have knowledge on this topic, what are the concrete answers to the questions posted?

Comment: The problem is that one should know all stack (and building). An error in one part would make the perfect plan in other parts irrelevant. I'm not an expert, but I used to use debugger on programs to see how their worked [before finding open source, which makes things easier and clearer]. So getting keys and decryption was easy [or just get a memory dump of unencoded data, when program is really running]. CPU and architectures supports some keys (all boot sequence is secure, so no leak of keys), but I never looked in details. security SE should know much better.